# В чем ошибка при запуске expo start?

Tags: react-native

Все нормально работало.Перебил винду ,теперь при запуске команды npm start ,expo start , получаю вот эту ошибку :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

обычные React приложения нормально запускаютсяВот что получается с флагом --verbose 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(обычные React приложения нормально запускаются)

Comment: По этому логу сложно сказать. Попробуйте тоже самое запустить с --verbose.

Comment: Добрый день.Приложил к записи фото  вызова той же команды с флагом --verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вызвана особенностями работы node v12.11.0 с регулярными выражениями([оригинал на англ.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120990/how-to-resolve-the-error-on-react-native-start)).

Два варианта решения проблемы:

1) Даунгрейд node до версии v12.10.0 пока проблема не будет решена разработчиками metro

2) Поправить регулярное выражение руками в этом файле:

`\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js`

С:

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

На:

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!